# Extending wires of wireless charger coils

Tags: wireless-charging

I have an original wireless charger:

[image]

I want to extend the wires to the coils to bring the charging pads further from the PCB, about 80-100 cm.

I would cut the wires (at the red), and apply new ones (green):

[image]

I don't want to modify anything else, just I want to separate the coils from the PCB. I don't see any performance drawbacks (if the proper wires are used).

Can I do this without worrying?

Comment: it depends on what kind of things you worry about ... what is your specific question that relates to electronics design?

Comment: I'd like to know if extending those wires affects (A) charging perfomance, (B) warming up, (C) other?

Comment: I'd worry why you want to cut the cables. It will be far easier to just unsolder them from the PCB, so no need to cut cables. The thing is we would not know what happens if you do that. It might just not work if you extend the coil. Or be less efficient. Or radiate too much electromagnetic interference.

Comment: Yes, by cutting I meant desolder + extended.

Comment: For example looking at the right side: extending four wires, shall I maintain the quasi-constant distance between the four cables all they way from PCB to coil? Or that doesn't really matter?

Comment: Are the coils series tuned or parallel tuned? Can you post a schematic?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this info yet, as I don't have (yet) this hardware. But I think the coils (on the right at least) can't be used at the same time. I.e. either the smaller coil is working, either the larger, it depends on what kind of device you put on the pad (small==watch, or large==phone).

Comment: I have a similar charger, but I really don't want to disassemble. Right side can charge both a phone or a watch (NOT at the same time!), while the left side (single coil) can only charge phones. If I put the watch onto the left side, nothing happens.

Comment: Here is the reference article where I have these pictures from: https://www.chargerlab.com/samsung-wireless-charger-duo-pad-ep-p5200-teardown-review/

Comment: "I want to extend its wires to the coils to bring the charging pads further from the pcb" Umm... why?! What exactly would you gain by doing so?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the length and how you put this new addition. Here are the factors that can affect the performance:

1. These wireless chargers are tuned to the resonance with a very narrow bandwidth. A change in resonance frequency can affect the performance significantly. If you can make sure new additions would not change coil inductances, then it may not affect resonance that much. One suggestion is to twist the terminals of each coil individually to minimize inductance change.
2. The addition of coils can easily increase coil resistance and increase the losses thus the heat generation. The recommendation is to use litz wire for the extension.

Anyway, in order to see the effects more precisely, there should be more information regarding what exactly you need to obtain, in which way.